# WPF disabled checkbox background color

Tags: wpf

How do I remove the light gray color that appears behind the text of the disabled checkboxes? Thanks in advance!

I have changed ALL system colors:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    ...
</Style.Resources>
```

but the background color behind text (when checkbox is Disabled) remains unchanged.

Comment: One option is don't disable.  Just have set not honor any change.

Comment: But in terms of usability, it is always better to tell the user if the control is active or not.

Comment: In terms of usability that is the purpose of the light gray color that you want to take away.

Comment: In terms of usability is enough to set the text color downgraded, it is not necessary a gray background.

Comment: I don't get a gray background on a disabled checkbox.

Comment: Ok, I'll check everything. Maybe I made a mistake. Anyway, yhanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Setting Focusable="False" and IsHitTestVisible="False" will "disable" the checkbox without changing the appearance of it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "behind the text."  The text itself becomes gray, but you can easily change the behavior using a `Trigger`:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" IsEnabled="False">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Obviously a very simplified example here.

Comment: The problem is not the color of the text, but the background color (light gray) that appears behind the text when IsEnables property is false. I've changed ALL the system colors, but that color remains unchanged.

Comment: @user3952846 Post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but googling still finds it as one of the top results. 
In this situation, you can just set `IsHitTestVisible = false` instead of `IsEnabled = false`.

This will display the checkbox as enabled while preventing any clicks within it.